# Ошибка компилятора C3646 при сборке проекта c++

Tags: c++

Есть два класса, имеющие экземпляры друг друга:

Файл **A.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "B.h"

class A
{
public:
    B b;
    A();
   ~A();
};
```

Файл **B.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h"

class B
{
public:
    A a;
    B();
   ~B();
};
```

Файл **A.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"

A::A()
{
}

A::~A()
{
}
```

Файл **B.cpp**

```
#include "B.h"

B::B()
{
}


B::~B()
{
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку: каков будет размер экземпляров этих классов?

Comment: "Есть два класса, имеющие экземпляры друг друга:"  - этого невозможно достичь. А какие вы будете получать при этом ошибки - дело десятое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определение класса с содержимым ещё не определённого класса - не позволено. В вашем случае вообще вы предлагаете класс объектов бесконечного размера.

Данный вопрос обычно решается указателями на другой класс.

```
class A ;

class B {
 A * a ;
};

//--

class B ;

class A {
B * b ;
};
```